# How to speed up django's delete()?

Tags: django, performance

Using MyModel.objects.all().delete() may take ***a lot*** of time. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Assumptions:

- I want to delete all instances of MyModel
- I also want to delete any models that have a ForeignKey to MyModel
- I know a priori which models they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [raw sql](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/):

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("set foreign_key_checks = 0")
cursor.execute("truncate table table_a")
cursor.execute("truncate table table_b")
# ...
cursor.execute("set foreign_key_checks = 1")
```

If you want to delete all models, you can even use the db to generate the sql statements:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("set foreign_key_checks = 0")
cursor.execute("select concat('truncate table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') as sql_stmt from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name' and table_type = 'base table'")
for sql in [sql[0] for sql in cursor.fetchall()]:
    cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.execute("set foreign_key_checks = 1")
```

(the sql tricks are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451726/empty-a-relational-database-schema))

Comment: I think that "set foreign_key_checks = 0" thing is for MySQL only, right?  On Oracle, you would have to explicitly disable each foreign key that points to a table before truncating it.  I found that in Oracle, I could keep 90% of the speed benefit by truncating my "child" table (many rows), then using a normal delete on my "parent" table (few rows).